# display divs always in 3 columns regardless of their heights in flex parent

Tags: css, position, flexbox

I need divs always to display in 3 columns regardless of their heights in flex parent and number of the divs (it can be 10 or more - but always in 3 columns - underneath each other) How do I make it? Code Pan example appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
<div class='main'>
<div class='div'>1</div>
<div class='div'>2</div>
<div class='div'>3</div>
<div class='div'>4</div>
</div>

.main {display:flex;flex-direction:row;background:silver;}
.div {width:33%; height:10px;background:gold;margin:10px;}
```

***Here is my EXAMPLE***http://codepen.io/broudi/pen/MyVNyz - there are 4 equal divs in parent flex div. I need no matter how much divs there are in parent div always to situate them in 3 columns(so one underneath another if first 3 places are taken).

***NEW EDIT: ANOTHER PROBLEM:*** HERE IS MY CODE:http://codepen.io/broudi/pen/MyVNyz

The problem is that if one or more of thechild dovs have height different then others then the div below doesnt go as it supposed to. it takes some space. Please, check out my CODEPAN example. How can I makkw inner divs no matter what go one after another with equal 5px margin regardless of their heights?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Can you give already some code? we can help but not write your code

Comment: Nope....read what I wrote....

Comment: Please, check out my edit and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give the parent `flex-wrap:wrap;` andto the div 30% not 33% because of the `margin:10px;`  and now you will always have a row of 3 div's

even put in `justify-content:space-around;` or `between` for that it looks better

```css
.main {display:flex;flex-direction:row;background:silver; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:space-around;}
.div {width:30%; height:10px;background:gold;margin:10px;}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
   <div class='div'>1</div>
   <div class='div'>2</div>
   <div class='div'>3</div>
   <div class='div'>4</div>
   <div class='div'>5</div>
   <div class='div'>6</div>
   <div class='div'>7</div>
   <div class='div'>8</div>
   <div class='div'>9</div>
   <div class='div'>10</div>
   <div class='div'>11</div>
   <div class='div'>12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: PLease, I have anpther issue - check out my updated codepan example. there is the problem.

Comment: i dont think there is a way to do what you want in flexbox